# Having memory leak problems when using gpio pulse

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I am using Lua and gpio.pulse to control gpio pins for stepper motor timing.

I have simplified the problem to a working case and a non working case. If I continuously call pulse:start with the same table everything is ok.

If this case successive calls need a different set of information, and calls to gpio.pulse.build result in leaking memory

This is fine

```
gpio.mode(1, gpio.OUTPUT, gpio.PULLUP)
gpio.mode(7, gpio.OUTPUT, gpio.PULLUP)

gpio.write(1, gpio.LOW)
gpio.write(7, gpio.LOW)

local stepAction = {}
table.insert(stepAction, { [7] = gpio.LOW, delay=500 })
table.insert(stepAction, { [7] = gpio.HIGH, delay=500, loop=1, count=10})
pulsar = gpio.pulse.build(stepAction)

mytimer = tmr.create()
mytimer:alarm(100, tmr.ALARM_SEMI, function (t)
    pulsar:start(function()
        print ('done:' .. node.heap())
        mytimer:start()
    end)
end)
```

but this leaks until out of memory

```
gpio.mode(1, gpio.OUTPUT, gpio.PULLUP)
gpio.mode(7, gpio.OUTPUT, gpio.PULLUP)

gpio.write(1, gpio.LOW)
gpio.write(7, gpio.LOW)


mytimer = tmr.create()
mytimer:alarm(100, tmr.ALARM_SEMI, function (t)
    local stepAction = {}
    table.insert(stepAction, { [7] = gpio.LOW, delay=500 })
    table.insert(stepAction, { [7] = gpio.HIGH, delay=500, loop=1, count=10})
    pulsar = gpio.pulse.build(stepAction)
    stepAction = nil
    pulsar:start(function()
        print ('done:' .. node.heap())
        mytimer:start()
    end)
end)
```

I have tried setting the stepAction to nil after the build call and calling pulsar:cancel

The node.heap prints the same number multiple times then drops 5-6k in a single call until out of memory.

Also tried setting node.egc.setmode(node.egc.ALWAYS) with the same result.

Am building a local versionof NodeMcu off master version 2.2.1

Had also tried as

```
local function IntervalTimerAction (timer)
    return function()
        local stepAction = {}
        table.insert(stepAction, { [7] = gpio.LOW, delay=500 })
        table.insert(stepAction, { [7] = gpio.HIGH, delay=500, loop=1, count=10})
        pulsar = gpio.pulse.build(stepAction)
        stepAction = nil
        pulsar:start(function()
            print ('done:' .. node.heap())
            timer:start()
        end)
    end
end

gpio.mode(1, gpio.OUTPUT, gpio.PULLUP)
gpio.mode(7, gpio.OUTPUT, gpio.PULLUP)

gpio.write(1, gpio.LOW)
gpio.write(7, gpio.LOW)

node.egc.setmode(node.egc.ALWAYS)
mytimer = tmr.create()
mytimer:alarm(1000, tmr.ALARM_SEMI, IntervalTimerAction(mytimer))
```

With the same result

Final try as per Egor's recommendation

```
local function IntervalTimerRestart (timer)
    return function()
        print ('done:' .. node.heap())
        timer:start()
    end
end

local function IntervalTimerAction (actions, timer)
    return function()
        for id, a in next, actions do
            actions[id] = nil
        end
        table.insert(actions, { [7] = gpio.LOW, delay=500 })
        table.insert(actions, { [7] = gpio.HIGH, delay=500, loop=1, count=10})
        pulsar = gpio.pulse.build(actions)
        pulsar:start(IntervalTimerRestart (timer))
    end
end

gpio.mode(1, gpio.OUTPUT, gpio.PULLUP)
gpio.mode(7, gpio.OUTPUT, gpio.PULLUP)

gpio.write(1, gpio.LOW)
gpio.write(7, gpio.LOW)

node.egc.setmode(node.egc.ALWAYS)
local stepAction = {}
mytimer = tmr.create()
mytimer:alarm(1000, tmr.ALARM_SEMI, IntervalTimerAction(stepAction, mytimer))
```

Same result will long a bug and post back here the result

Comment: Try to move the callback function used by `pulsar:start` outside of the timer callback.  Define this function at the beginning of your program and invoke `pulsar:start(my_callback)`.

Comment: I think that my edit is what you were suggesting, but still the same result

Comment: My suggestion was to avoid creating new pulser callback function inside timer callback.  So that your program has unique pulser callback function.  Your edit still creates new function instance every time timer callback activated.  (Why `newTimer` is needed?  Let's start by solving the problem for single timer object)

Comment: 1. Make sure you didn't disable the GC 2. Make sure you're not somehow preventing the temporary tables from being collected 3. trigger garbage collection manually and see what happens 4. see if you can clear and re-use the existing table (this is good practive anyway, as it leads to less garbage being collected, which means faster execution)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Sorry I did not interpret your comment correctly, and my change did not make a lot of sense in hindsight (late at night). I have changed it as indicated with the same result. The memory is stable for 15-40 iterations then drops ~ 5k

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer I have re-enabled the GC in it's most aggressive form as shown in the latest edit. wrt to the table clear, I thought that assigning a table to {} was the recommended way. I am new to lua, so probably missing something, but can see no clear on a table. Should I iterate through and set to nil?

Comment: If re-using of callback function did not help, then try to re-use both the callback function (which is the argument for `pulsar:start`) and the `stepAction` table (traverse all keys to remove old content and then insert new instructions).  From the point of view of pure Lua, your program is absolutely correct, the problem is that nodemcu anchors some objects internally, so that GC is unable to collect them.  You should file a bug to nodemcu team.  What we are discussing here is how to workaround this bug.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff hey thanks for the quick response. Will give that a try when I get home (at work at the moment) and will post a bug regardless of the result.

Comment: Inside `IntervalTimerRestart (timer)` you are still creating new function.  Do not do this.  Reuse one function instead of creating new function every time.